# Calling JS function from a CSHTML Script Tag, in another wwwroot/JS file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-core, frontend

Apologies if this is a duplicate question. I have been trying to look for similar questions for the past few days. Would be grateful if you could guide me to the duplicate question.

***Question-***
I am using a JS function inside a `<script>` tag in a `view/CSHTML` file.
I am trying to execute that function from another `wwwroot/JS` file

***Attempt***
I would try ordering the JS scripts such that I add script tag for the javascript(which has my function) before consuming ones, but as the consuming one is actually a library that is used in the javascript(which has my function)

I tried `export function function_name(){ ... }` and
`import { function_name} from "../../Views/Home/FileName.cshtml";`
This was unsuccessful because of ECMAScript level incompatibilities.

Comment: If the function needs to be shared across multiple pages then it sounds like it should be in a `.js` file, not directly on a specific page.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @David, but the function is not being shared across multiple pages. It is for the same page. And I am using a combination of inline and external JS for it. I need to keep some variables and functions inline for the front-end maps and viz templates that I am using in my ASP.NET Core web-app

Comment: If all of the relevant JavaScript code is being executed in the same page context, how is this function defined such that the rest of the code can't see it?  Can you provide an example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: I have two pages Live Visualizations and Archived Viz. 

Both pages have some inline JS to manipulate the page using the Viz Templates. (this inline JS can not be in an external .JS file -- tied to the templates and widgets on their respective pages)

Additionally, I have an external .JS file, which controls certain front-end behaviour, which is common for both pages. 

What I'm trying to do now, is execute an inline js function from archived viz, inside the external JS file. (which is unable to see the function I need)

Does that make sense? 

Comment: But why is the code "unable to see the function"?  How are you defining that function and how are you trying to use it?  An example would really help clarify the problem.